# BASH name-clash between function input and awk argument

Tags: string, bash, function, input, awk

I wish to dynamically get the first file inside a folder. What I have tried so far:

```sh
get_first_file () {
    local folder_name=$1
    filenames=`ls $folder_name/*`
    first_file=(echo ${filenames} | awk '{print $1}')

get_first_file my_folder
```

This produces the following error:

```
my_shell_script.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
my_shell_script.sh: line 4: `    first_file=(echo ${filenames} | awk '{print $1}')'
```

Please help me understand what this error means, and how it can be resolved.

Comment: You have basic syntax errors.  There are bigger issues, but the syntax error can be resolved with: `get_first_file () { local dir=$1; filenames=$(ls $dir/*); first_file=$(echo ${filenames} | awk '{print $1}'); }`

Comment: In particular, you're missing the `$` on the process substitution and the terminating `}` on the function definition.

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you, @WilliamPursell , exactly what I needed. If you turn the comment content into an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue with your code.  I'll just address the syntax errors:

```
get_first_file () {
    local folder_name=$1
    filenames=`ls $folder_name/*`
    first_file=$(echo ${filenames} | awk '{print $1}')
}

get_first_file my_folder
```

There's really no need for the intermediate variables, but perhaps you are using `filenames` at the global scope, so there's nothing wrong with using them.  Backticks have been effectively obsolete for decades and should never be used, and parsing the output of `ls` like this is generally not a good idea.

You really ought not do this, though.  In particular, allowing word splitting on the echo to munge all the whitespace and generate a single line of output to be filtered by `awk` is weird.  You can get away with this if your filenames are well behaved, but it's not good practice.  Perhaps it would be better to write something like:

```
get_first_file () {
        first_file=$(for i in *; do echo "$i"; exit; done;)
}
```

or

```
get_first_file () {
        first_file=$(find "$1" -not -name '.*' -maxdepth 1 -print0 | 
        perl -0ne 'print if $. == 1')
}
```

but it's not clear what you're doing with `filenames`